# Input based tags in XML

Tags: xsd

Can any one please help me ! ! is there any way how we can define input based tag in XSD to generate XML ?

for ex :

```
<Element1>Hi</Element1>
<Element2>Hello</Element2>
```

if Hi is there in Element1 then element2 tag is mandatory otherwise it is optional.

i know there are lots of threads for this but i m not able to get that properly.

~Aditya

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to support this in XSD 1.0. You can however use the http://www.schematron.com/ for enforcing these kind of rules.

If you can use XSD 1.1 then look at [co-occurence constraints](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/)